# How to Induct this Statement?

Tags: calculus, summation, proof-writing, induction, geometric-series

I would like to prove the following proposition by induction:

> For all $m\in\mathbb N$, we have $\sum_{i=1}^m \frac{i}{(i+1)!} = 1 - \frac{1}{(m+1)!}.$

First, I prove the base step $m = 1$:

$\sum_{i=1}^1 \frac{i}{(i+1)!}$ = 1 - $\frac{1}{(2)!}$, which is effectively $\frac{1}{2}$ on both sides of this equation.

Next, I assume that there is some $k\in\mathbb N$ such that
$$
\sum_{i=1}^k \frac{i}{(i+1)!} = 1 - \frac{1}{(k+1)!}
$$

Now, to prove the inductive step I do:
$$
\sum_{i=1}^{k+1} = 1 - \frac{1}{(k+1)!} + \frac{k+1}{(k+2)!}
$$

At this point, I don't know what to do because I think I messed up at the last step. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're almost there. From $1 - \frac{1}{(k+1)!} + \frac{k+1}{(k+2)!}$ note that $\frac{1}{(k+1)!} = \frac{k+2}{(k+2)!}$ and you can finish the proof.

Comment: Right, but now I'm getting. $1 - \frac{2k+3}{(k+2)!}$. Is this correct?

Comment: @jojanqo Check your $+$ and $-$ signs.

Comment: Oh, is it supposed to be $1 - \frac{1}{(k+2)!}$